# In Python how can I combine the elements in two lists into one list? Not appending the list

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
   list1 = ['1','2','3']

   list2 = ['4','5','6']
```

desire list3 to be ['14','25','36']

Is there a python built in function that can do this?

I have searched for a method to do this but have not found anything. Everything all the functions simply append one list to the other.  Not what I want to do

Answer (score 2):

We can do it using map:

```
list1 = ['1', '2', '3']
list2 = ['4', '5', '6']

list3 = list(map(''.join, zip(list1, list2)))
print(list3)

#['14', '25', '36']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list3 = [x+y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To iterate through several lists at a time, you can use the zip() function.
Something like this would work:

```
list1 = ['1','2','3']
list2 = ['4','5','6']
list3 = [a + b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

The zip function will iterate through both lists, concatenate each element, and put the result into list3.